# What happens to brokerage accounts during severe financial crises?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, current-events, government, greece

It's well known that during, for example, the recent Argentinian great depression (1998-2002) or the ongoing Greek government-debt crisis, the bank accounts of members of the public were frozen, and clients were unable to access cash due to withdrawal rationing and a run on the banks, and similar.  What typically happens to brokerage accounts during similar situations?

Comment: That's really dependent on where you are. Which country are you asking about in particular?

Comment: I live in the UK, but would be interested to hear examples from similar situations in other countries.  I am aware, for instance, that in certain circumstances, e.g. 9/11, stock exchanges have frozen trading.

Comment: Cursory google searches haven't found much about the LSE closing since the 1914 emergency. Given that the City is an essential financial hub, I doubt it would be shut for very long.

Answer (score 2):

> What typically happens to brokerage accounts during similar situations?

This depends on country, time and situation. Nothing is predictable in such situations. In Greece during the said period the stock exchanges were closed for 5 weeks. There was no trading.

Edits:
Every situation is different and it would be unfair to compare one against another or use it to predict something else. Right now in India due to demonitization, cash withdrawal is limited. One can trade in stocks, unlimited bank transfers, transfer money out of India ...etc. Everything same except for cash withdrawal. In 1990, the ASEAN countries survived a financial collapse, everything was allowed except moving money out of country.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dheer.  As per the comment above, I live in the UK, but would be interested to hear examples from similar situations in other countries.